# $\mathbb{E}[X^4]=1$, $X,Y$ iid, what's the best upper bound of $\mathbb{E}[(X-Y)^4]$?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, oc.optimization-and-control, real-algebraic-geometry, moments

Let $X,Y$ be *i.i.d.* random variables, $\mathbb{E}[X^4]=1$, what's the best upper bound for $\mathbb{E}[(X-Y)^4]$ ?

1. A trivial upper bound is $16$, since $(X-Y)^4 \leq 8 (X^4+Y^4)$ then take expectation on both sides. However, equality cannot be achieved.
2. My guess of the best upper bound will be $8$, achieved when $X$ is uniform at random from $\{-1, +1\}$.

Comment: Concerning the close vote: Such inequalities do pop up in some research and even get published; see e.g. http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.122.5.479?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents or the arxiv version of the same note at https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.6220

Answer (score 36, accepted):

$\newcommand{\de}{\delta}
\newcommand{\De}{\Delta}
\newcommand{\ep}{\epsilon}
\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}
\newcommand{\Ga}{\Gamma}
\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}
\newcommand{\Si}{\Sigma}
\newcommand{\thh}{\theta}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{\mathsf E}} 
\newcommand{\PP}{\operatorname{\mathsf P}}
\newcommand{\ii}[1]{\operatorname{\mathsf I}\{#1\}}$

Your guess is correct. Indeed, it is well known (see e.g. [Bertsimas--Popesku, page 781](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S1052623401399903?journalCode=sjope8)) that real numbers $m_0=1,m_1,\dots,m_{2\ell}$ are the moments of orders $0,1,\dots,2\ell$ of a real-valued random variable $X$ iff the matrix $M:=(m_{i+j})_{i,j=0}^\ell$ is nonnegative-definite, that is, iff all the principal minors of $M$ are $\ge0$; here $\ell$ is a natural number; in our case, $\ell=2$. 
Also, given $\E X^4=1$, we have 
\begin{equation}
 \E(X-Y)^4=2-8m_3m_1+6m_2^2. 
\end{equation}
Thus, the problem is a simple problem of real algebraic geometry, which can be solved algorithmically. Using the Mathematica command Maximize[], we get the result:

[image]

---

**Added:** Here is an elementary solution, without using Mathematica: Since $m_4=1$, the condition $\det M\ge0$ implies
\begin{equation}
 2m_3m_1\ge m_2^2-m_4+(m_3^2+m_4m_1^4)/m_2\ge m_2^2-1,
\end{equation}
whence
\begin{equation}
 \E(X-Y)^4=2-8m_3m_1+6m_2^2\le2-4(m_2^2-1)+6m_2^2=2m_2^2+6\le8, 
\end{equation}
since $m_2^2\le m_4=1$. The equality in the inequality in question  is attained only if $m_2^2=m_4=1$ and $2m_3m_1=m_2^2-1=0$, that is, only if $\PP(X=1)=\PP(X=-1)=1/2$.

Comment: Note that your formula is $\operatorname{trace}(M D MD)$ where $D$ is a matrix with alternating plus and minus signs. The same works for the analogous problem with $(X-Y)^{2\ell}$. However, I wasn't able to use this idea to solve the analogous problem.

Comment: I have added an elementary solution, without using Mathematica.